# Table collapses with Bootstrap 4 d-md-inline

Tags: html, css

I have the following HTML table:

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">
<table class="w-100">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <td>Heading 1</td>
      <td>Heading 2</td>
      <td>Heading 3</td>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>Item 1</td>
      <td>Item 2</td>
      <td>Item 3</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

This displays properly and stretches across the page (i.e., container).

If I add `d-none d-md-inline` to the `<table>` tag, the table collapses.  I've also tried `d-md-inline-block` and `d-md-block` but neither works.

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">
<table class="w-100 d-none d-md-inline">
      <thead>
        <tr>
          <td>Heading 1</td>
          <td>Heading 2</td>
          <td>Heading 3</td>
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
        <tr>
          <td>Item 1</td>
          <td>Item 2</td>
          <td>Item 3</td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>
```

THE POINT:  I want a table to display when on a MD screen or larger, and I want the big table to disappear when on a SM or XS screen (i.e., mobile).  It functions correctly when moving the width of the window and when it hits the SM breakpoint, it disappears.  The problem is that the table is collapsed onto itself and does not stretch (like justified) across the container width.

How do I get the table to display properly in MD and bigger but disappear on SM and XS?

FIND THE CODE AT JSFIDDLE

https://jsfiddle.net/jallenmorris/m5ct40wd/10/

Comment: Thansk CCCN for the suggested edit.

Comment: I can make it work with `<div>` tags. https://jsfiddle.net/jallenmorris/avd4Ltjy/12/ like found here.  Isn't there a way to re-order items in Bootstrap 4 so the display changes to be correct in smaller screens?

Comment: For some reasons thead and tbody are collapsing when display: block affect on them, I have no idea why this is happen

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add one `wrapper` on a `table` like & add this class `d-none d-md-block` for `wrapper` div

```
<div class="d-none d-md-block">
  <table class="table">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th>Heading 1</th>
        <th>Heading 2</th>
        <th>Heading 3</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td>Item 1</td>
        <td>Item 2</td>
        <td>Item 3</td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</div>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/lalji1051/sdq03co9/4/

Comment: Thank you!  I was just able to edit my code with your suggestion and it worked perfectly.  Now I don't have to mess with the order feature of Bootstrap.  All I have to do is show a different table for small screens.  Though I don't like loading the data twice with one version always being invisible.